# If $x,y\in (0,1]$ and $xy$ is rational, are $x$ and $y$ algebraic

Tags: number-theory, analysis

I'm working on the problem already specified in the title.
As the "easy" counterexamples - $x= 0$ or $y = 0$ - are excluded by the definition of the problem, I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: $\frac{2}{\pi}\cdot\frac{\pi}{5}=\frac{2}{5}$.

Comment: @JustinYoung thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

No. Let $a=\frac{4}{5}$ say. Then for every $x \in (0,1)$ there is a $y$ such that $x^y =a$. Now the set of such $x$ that are transcendental is uncountable and has measure 1, while the set of alegraic $x, y \in (0,1)$ has measure 0. So the set of $x \in (0,1)$ s.t. either $x$ or $y=\frac{\ln a}{\ln x}$ is algebraic has measure 0. Thus there has to be an transcendental $x$ and a transcandental $y$ such that $x^y=4/5$.

ETA this line of reasoning holds for $x × y=a$ as well; the set of such $x$ that either $x$ or $y$ is transcendental has measure 0, so almost all pairs $x,y$ s.t. $x×y=a$ are s.t. both $x$ and $y$ are transcendental.